# 49" Ultra Wide Screen Stretches Low Resolutions to Wrong Aspect Ratio on Win10 2004

Tags: windows, resolution

This 49" monitor, Dell UltraSharp 49 Curved Monitor: U4919DW, native resolution is 5120x1440, and this works fine. However in the past if I wanted a lower resolution i.e. to run games at higher FPS, or to share screen with someone that doesn't have a high res screen I would lower the screen to a resolution such as 1920x1080. This would display fine with the screen centered and black bars at either side of the screen.

However at some point this stopped working, I'm not sure exactly what changed when it broke as I only set it lower occasionally.
What happens now is lower resolution gets stretched to the full width of the screen.

The recent changes are:

- KB4569745 Cumulative Update for .NET 3.5/4.8
- KB4565503 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 2004
- KB4561600 Security Update for Adobe Flash Player
- Windows Subsystem for Linux Update 4.19.104

Drive Updates:

- Rivet Network LLC 2.2.3275.0
- Intel System 2021.14.0.1615
- Dell Firmware 0.1.7.0
- Realtek 1.0.0.254
- Intel net 21.90.2.1
- Realtek 1.0.0.5
- Realtek Semiconductor 10.0.17134.1
- Realtek 11.0.60000.771
- Intel 2.7.101.2
- Intel Extension 1.41.823.0

What I've tried:

- Change aspect ratio on monitor, this can resolve it but only for resolutions with 4:3 aspect ratio, and in the past this never needs to be set. This has settings:

Wide 32:9
Auto Resize
4:3
1:1

Currently set to 1:1 but also tried Auto Resize.

- Factory reset on monitor
- Tried to check all graphics drivers if they could be "Rolled back" in device manager, but none had this option available.
- Checked monitor firmware, currently running latest version
- DPI scaling is set to 100%

Connection is over HDMI from Dell XPS 15 7590.

Any idea of other configuration options that may impact this?

Comment: Usually you can enable resizing with/without keeping aspect ration also in graphics driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to open Intel UHD Graphics Control Panel and change setting "Scale Full Screen" to "Maintain Aspect Ratio"

This application had updated and changed the setting in the process.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this settings panel. Oddly enough, all I had to do was to set the refresh rate to 100p and the issue was sorted.